# Managed package not listed on appexchange

Tags: managed-package, package, licenses, lma

We have created a managed package that is going through security review and is not yet listed on appexchange. We have a potential customer who wants to try out our app. We are unsure as to how to go about billing and managing licenses for this customer as we do not have the partner business org or LMA assigned to us.

- Do we need to wait for the app to pass security review before it can be given to the customer?
- If not, Can someone guide as to how we can go about billing/licensing the customer?
- Once the app gets approved, how do we transition this customer in LMA?
- Anything else, we need to keep in mind for such early customers regarding package management?

Comment: It is possible to get the LMA for a managed package that isn't yet in the app exchange. Try following the steps under [Get Started with the License Management App](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.workbook_lma.meta/workbook_lma/lma_setup.htm). You will need to be in the Partner Program, but that should already be the case if your app is in security review.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I went through the link you mentioned. It seems I can associate LMA with another org for the managed package. But is it possible to later change the LMA org to the business org after the security review goes through?